# Actions SDK, Linked Account: Indicating that the access_token is no longer valid (and needs to be refreshed) or that the account needs to be re-linked

Tags: actions-on-google

We're currently working on a project that requires the users' accounts to be linked to one of our client's services via the oAuth2 authorization flow.

However, there is the possibility that tokens expire **before** the expires_in duration that's returned with the token from the oAuth2 token endpoint, or that the user simply revokes the token/authorization. In that case a new token needs to be fetched via the refresh-token-flow, or the Account needs to be re-linked altogether.

Is there some way for us to indicate to Google (in the HTTP response returned by the fulfilment backend, or via some other way) that the access_token is no longer valid and needs to be refreshed, or that the Account needs to be relinked?

For instance, with Alexa, it is possible to return an "Account Linking Card" in the HTTP response along with the actual speech that's read back to the user. 
This "card" then starts the account linking process on Amazon's side(even if the Account was already linked before). Is there an equivalent to this in the Actions SDK?

If there is no way for us to indicate to Google that the Account Linking is no longer valid and needs to be redone or refreshed, is there at least some way to programmatically "unlink" an Account (which would then automatically trigger the Account Linking process on the next invocation)?